# Transfer gestures on a UIView to a UITableView in Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a layout with a `UIView` at the top of the page and, right below it, I have a `UITableView`.

What I am wanting to do is to transfer the gesture interactions on the `UIView` to the `UITableView`, so when the user makes a drag up/down on the `UIView`, the `UITableView` scrolls vertically.

I tried the following code

```
tableView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { uiView.addGestureRecognizer($0) }
```

but it removed the gestureRecognizers from the `UITableView` somehow :/

---

**Obs.: the `UIView` cannot be a `Header` of the `UIScrollView`**

Comment: Do you need user interaction on the UIView? If not you can disable it and the touch will be recognized by the UITableView i think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's Tricky

### What is problem ?

> Your top view is not allowed to pass through view behind it...

### What would be possible solutions

1. pass all touches to view behind it (Seems to not possible or very tough practically  )
2. Tell window to ignore touches on top view (Easy one)

Second option is better and easy.

So What you need to do is create subclass of `UIView` and `override`

```
 override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
```

and return nil if you found same view on `hitTest` action

Here Tested and working example

```
class PassThroughME : UIView {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event) == self ? nil : self
    }
}
```

That's it now use  `PassThroughME` either by adding class to your view in storyboard or programmatically whatever way you have added your view

Check image i have black color view with 0.7 alpha on top still i am able to scroll

[image]

Hope it is helpful

Comment: @VictorM Thank you for the very kind words.  this made my day. :)