# iOS: How to pass scroll through collection view to another collection view behind it

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a problem with setting up with two `CollectionView`. My case:
On the top of the screen, I have `CollectionView` (A) with recommended products (which is `CollectionView` with simple `imageview`). On top of that, I have another `CollectionView` with an edge `inset` top set for the same `height` value as `CollectionView` behind it (B).

[image: Sample hierarchy]

I've set the hit test in `CollectionView` B

```
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if (collectionView.contentOffset.y + point.y) > 0 {
            return collectionView
        } else {
            return bannerViewContainer.hitTest(point, with: event)
        }
    }
```

Which basically checks if touch is on the area of the gray cells or on the area with A `CollectionView` behind it. This solution works so if I want to scroll `CollectionView` A horizontally and B `vertically`. But when I want to `scroll` `CollectionView` B up or down in the `CollectionView` A area, I can't do it because touch is passed through.

The problem is - is there any solution to `scroll` `CollectionView` B up and down no matter when I start my touch and A left to right when I touch in the A `CollectionView` area?

Comment: Why you are not using **CollectionView A** as a header of **UiTableview**? Same this I have done in this app https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/bayside-sports/id1446269865?mt=8

Comment: What if you scroll it diagonally?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49940454/4601900

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I don't want to use collection view as header because I want to have refresh control below collection view A and above collection view B which is hard to achieve when I put collection view A to the header.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya This is not what I asked for. Basically solution you mentioned is implemented above - look at the hitTest method. I don't want to ignore all touches. I want to pass them through.