# Let UIImageView pass tap to view behind it

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have UICollectionViewCell in which i have a UIImageView of 100X100.
I have added a tap gesture to collectionView cell contentView.
When user click on image , tagGesture method not getting called. Any way I can make UIImageView to pass that gesture to contentView which is just behind it. I don't want to add another tap gesture to UIImageView.

Comment: I think you should review your question. it's not clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer gestures on a UIView to a UITableView in Swift - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939405/transfer-gestures-on-a-uiview-to-a-uitableview-in-swift-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Create this subclass and set it to the class name of the imageView

```
class TransImgV:UIImageView { 
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {  
        return false
    } 
}
```